# Maximum energy reached by LHC

Tags: experimental-physics, accelerator-physics

I was trying to compute what is the maximum energy reached by the LHC assuming it has a circunference of 27 km length and the magnetic field of the magnets is ~8 T. To do that, I tried comparing the centripetal force suffered by protons $mv^2/R$ where $m$ is the mass of the proton, $v$ the speed of the particle and $R$ the radius of the circunference with the electromagnetic force $qvB$, with $q$ the charge of a proton and $B$ the magnetic field strength. If I do this, I'm getting a speed larger than the speed of light, so I guess I'm screwing up in some reasoning...

Comment: Likely because you aren't including relativistic effects and only treating it with the classical equation

Comment: so both forces cannot be equaled?

Comment: No it's just you cannot use classical mechanics in a regime where something is traveling with near speed of light velocity

Comment: then what do you suggest compute the energy of the accelerator? I even found the approximation $p_{max}=0.3BR$ (with $p$ in GeV/c, $B$ in Tesla and $R$ in meters), but I do not know how to derive it

Comment: You may want to look at this related question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20919/relativistic-centripetal-force

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proton is relativistic so the centrifugal force term is different. The correct relativistic relation is amazingly simple: $p=0.3 BR$. (Units GeV/c, Tesla, meters).

Your estimate will be a bit high as the ring is not fully occupied by magnets. There are gaps for RF, collimators, quadrupoles, and other components.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already had that relation but I wanted to understand how to derive it (don't like to apply formulae without knowing their origin...)

Comment: Good policy. Should have added that 0,3 is $c$ times $10^{-9}$ because of using Giga eV.