# Relativistic Centripetal Force/Centrifugal Effect

Tags: special-relativity, forces, acceleration, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

I wonder how would we go about to calculate centripetal/centrifugal acceleration for relativistic objects moving at near the speed of light , do we use the original acceleration = force/mass, or input gamma factor for it to be ,
Acceleration = (gamma) force / mass ,
Acceleration = Force / (gamma) mass
Which one is valid ? If both aren't is there a particular way and/or equation to calculate centripetal and centrifugal acceleration for relativistic objects ? How ?

Comment: try [wiki: acceleration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration_(special_relativity)), although if we're measuring centrifugal force (that is, we're in the accelerated frame and we want to know our weight), we don't need relativity at all, just a calibrated spring.

Comment: Duplicate: [Relativistic centripetal force](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20919/relativistic-centripetal-force)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swinging a rest-mass M tied to a rope around:

Force measured at that end of the rope to which the mass is tied: $F_2 = \gamma^2*M*a$

Force measured at that end of the rope that is the opposite end to which the mass is tied: $F_1 = \gamma*M*a$

$a$ is the velocity change of mass M per unit of time measured by a clock at the center of the circle formed by the path of the mass M.

Comment: I do want more clarification regarding whether we can use a = f/(gamma) mass, specifically on whether it is valid or not

Comment: @A Curious Mind Transverse acceleration is proportional to force, and inversely proportional to $\gamma*m_0$ , where  $m_0$ means rest-mass.  Hey, this would make a better answer : )

Comment: Okay then , I heard online that I had to calculate the derivative of the four dimensional momentum , is that true ? Or do we add a gamma and modify the centripetal acceleration equation in a unique way? What do you think?

Comment: @A Curious Mind Four-momentum not needed, as force transverse to motion is a simple case. As I said, use gamma times rest-mass ("relativistic mass") as the m in the a=F/m. And use F as F, unless you have a F felt by a road when a runner makes a turn, and you want to know g force felt by the runner.