# When was it possible to observe the special-relativistic modification of Energy?

Tags: special-relativity, energy, experimental-physics, speed-of-light, history

I am preparing a lecture for high-school students, and was wondering when it would have been possible to observe the special-relativistic modification of the Energy-velocity relation.

In more detail, in classical mechanics the kinetic energy is related to velocity by

$$E^{class}_{kin}=\frac{mv^2}{2}$$
This was first written down in that form by Émilie du Châtelet in the 1720s-1730s. In special relativity, the kinetic energy is given by

$$E^{SRT}_{kin}=\frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}-mc^2.$$

We can now Taylor-expand $E^{SRT}_{kin}$ and get
$$E^{SRT}_{kin}=\frac{mv^2}{2}+\frac{3 m v^4}{8 c^2} + O(v^6)$$

Now, one could have started from the classical energy formula at the time of Émilie du Châtelet and make a wild guess:

$$E^{guess}_{kin}=\frac{mv^2}{2} + \alpha v^3 + \beta v^4 + O(v^5)$$

Of course, nowadays we know that $\alpha$=0 and $\beta=\frac{3 m}{8 c^2}$ -- but in the early 1700s this was of course unknown. So a natural question is:

**My question is:**
What would have been the earliest possible experiments that could have observed a non-zero value of $\beta$? Could Faraday have seen this with the techniques at his disposal? Or even earlier?

Comment: Would [hsm.se] be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 7):

I think that the point where technology reached the relativistic realm was when the first cyclotrons started to accelerate particles to relativistic velocities.

The very first cyclotron was a tabletop device. If memory serves me, within years of the first one a cyclotron was built with a chamber two meters in diamter. Each larger design accelerated to higher velocities.

The operating principle of a cyclotron is quite neat:
The centripetal force that is required to make the particle(s) move in circumnavigating motion is provided by the Lorentz force. Electromagnets are set up in such a way that there is a uniform magnetic field.

In the chamber the circumnavigating particles are spiraling outward; as the particles are being accelerated (twice every circumnavigation), they are going round in wider and wider circles. Upon every acceleration the velocity of the particles increases. However, the *angular velcity* of the particles remains the same because the particles are going round in wider and wider circles.

As we know: the larger the radius of circumnavigating motion, the larger the required centripetal force. The Lorentz force accommodates that perfectly; the Lorentz force is proportional to the *velocity*.

So: in the non-relativistic realm the proportionalities are linear, allowing a wonderfully simple cyclotron design.

The designers/builders of cyclotons knew in advance this linear behavior is limited to the non-relativistic realm.

Pushing for relativistic velocities the designers knew they had to take into account that a higher magnetic field density is required when the particles are accelerated up to relativistic velocities.

One approach is to create a specific non-uniform magnetic field. For instance, if you make the magnetic field stronger the farther away from the center then the machine can still have all particles go round at the same angular velocity.

In a ring accelerator, such as the Large Hadron Collider, the field strength of the deflecting magnets is increased over time, in order to keep providing the required deflection. In the case of the Large Hadron Collider: the particles that are injected are already close to the speed of light. Over a period of 20 minutes or so the kinetic energy of the particles is raised further. The strength of the deflecting magnetic fields is adjusted upward continously in order to keep providing the required deflection.

Summerizing:
particle accelerators were the first machines for which it was necessary to take relativistic effect into account. Not taking relativistic effect into account would result in poor performance.

Further reading: 2012 question titled [Relativistic centripetal force](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/20919/relativistic-centripetal-force)

Comment: The question is effectively about relativistic mass, so to answer the part on the time frame when it was realized that it increases with speed, it was [about the end of 1890s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_special_relativity#History_of_the_relativistic_mass_concept).

Comment: Thanks. When would it have been possible to build an particle accelerator which allows to observe non-zero beta within the measurement accuracy of the time. Ruslan's wonderful link (thanks!) answer indicate that JJ Thomson in 1881 had experimental evidence already. Would it be possible earlier?

Answer (score -2):

I have plotted the function $f(x)=\frac{x^{4}}{c^{2}}$ [in Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/rpqru2pf0h)

As you see the graph looks like a pretty straight line until we reach a velocity of 80000m/s.So the poeple back then would have been able to notice the deviation from the $\frac{1}{2}mu^{2}$ only if a object of 1/3 kg was travelling at a velocity of 80000m/s.I dont think even their cannons were powerful enough back then to do such a thing.

Comment: The velocity scale at which the curve turns up depends solely on the range of your plot.

Comment: I have a plot illustrating KE that uses a log scale for the velocity here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/595175/123208

Comment: BTW, Earth's orbital speed is ~29 km/s, multiply that by $\sqrt2$ to get the solar system escape velocity at 1 AU. So a body moving at 80 km/s has almost 4× the kinetic energy needed to travel to the stars. ;)

Comment: @Sten no?Scaling is just a way to visualise something , it doesnt change the values.

Comment: You're plotting a power law. It has no characteristic scale. The scale you are seeing is entirely set by the vertical range of the plot.

Comment: @Sten you can just ZOOM OUT?To see the entire plot?

Comment: I can't zoom vertical and horizontal axis independently, or at least, it's not obvious how to. They have different dimensions, so there's no reason to give them the same limits.

Comment: Here is what I mean, https://www.desmos.com/calculator/thnysuglxc . I changed the vertical limit, and now the upturn is around 5000 m/s.

Comment: @PM2Ring you are assuming people KNEW the mass of the Earth.

Comment: @PM2Ring you said solar system escape velocity .This shows the gravitational force of the Sun not the Earth's.

Comment: @Cerise Oops. (I shouldn't post just before falling asleep). But Earth's mass is (mostly) irrelevant for that. They knew the Earth's orbit speed, roughly. And estimates on that speed improved in the late 18th century, with improved estimates of the astronomical unit (via measurements of the transits of Venus). By the early 1800s, we had quite good estimates of the Sun's gravity, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_gravitational_constant